# Выделение подстроки с помощью регулярного выражения C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Имеется строка вида:

> sdfdsg sad asdf - ehwstj sdhgf sgjfdg

Как можно составить регулярку, чтобы вытащить правую часть строки после "-"?

Comment: А зачем для такого простого действия вообще регулярки использовать? Обычный линейный алгоритм без наворотов, пропускаем символы до нужного, оставшиеся копируем в новую строку. Или я не правильно понял задачу?

Comment: Интересны всего лишь различные варианты реализации задачи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string pattern = "-";
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Comment: А возможно обойтись без создания массива? В данном случае исходная строка просто же разбивается на части и они записываются в массив. Хотелось бы, чтобы просто необходимая часть была в виде новой строки.

Comment: Нет нельзя. И почитайте о том как clr работает со строками

Comment: @Bezarius Можно, только в 2 строчки не получится и придется разбираться с StringBuilder, хотя результат может оказаться гораздо лучше и по памяти, и по производительности. Если понадобится. могу привести решение, только регулярками там не пахнет, ни к чему они. А в остальном полностью согласен с вашем решением.

Comment: для данного случая можно было и обычный Split  использовать а не Regex :-)

Comment: @rdorn я имел ввиду, что в конкретно данном случае нельзя избавиться от массива, т.к. он результат работы.

Comment: Grundy можно было, но просили регулярку :)

Comment: @rdorn а как будет выглядеть Ваше решение с StringBuilder?

Comment: У вас тут отличный ответ про то, как изменить кодировку коммита. Может, опубликуете его как ответ к новому вопросу именно про это? Не хотелось бы терять знания ) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481056/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin окей=)

Comment: @Corvin "а как будет выглядеть Ваше решение с StringBuilder?" добавил

Answer (score 3):

По просьбе автора решение без регулярных выражений и массивов в результате.

```
string s = "sdfdsg sad asdf - ehwstj sdhgf sgjfdg";
string result;
int i = 0;
//Пропускаем левую часть строки до '-' 
while (s[i] != '-' && i < s.Length) i++;
//Пропускаем '-'
i++;
int newLel = s.Length - (i + 1);
if (newLel > 0)
{
    //Создаем StringBuilder нужного размера
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(newLel);
    //По желанию пропускаем ведущие пробелы
    while (s[i] == ' ' && i < s.Length) i++;
    //Заносим оставшееся в StringBuilder
    while (i < s.Length)
    {
        sb.Append(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    result = sb.ToString();
}
else
{
    result = string.Empty; //или null, в зависимости от задачи
}
```

StringBuilder - специальный класс для сборки строк из произвольных фрагментов. Размер можно и не задавать, он подстраивается автоматически, но ресайз массива - дорогая операция, так что лучше задать сразу. Не смотря на количество кода, каждый символ строки просматривается ровно один раз. свойство Length класса String вычисляется при создании строки и возвращает всегда константу, т.к. строки неизменяемы. Остальное не должно вызвать трудностей.

Answer (score 1):

Без массивов:

```
Regex.Match("sdfdsg sad asdf - ehwstj sdhgf sgjfdg", @"(?<=-\s+).*").Value
```